# Using onClick event to match the correct word and continue Or set an alert on a wrong word

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

`I am trying to design my code so that`;

1. `If the user clicks the right word it continues on to the next word`
2. `If a wrong word is clicked then an alert is set`.

`However even when a correct word is clicked the alert is rendered!!`

It seems like I'm doing something wrong in the click event.

**Code sample**

```
const ParFour = () => {
  const [boxPosition, setBoxPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const containerSize = { width: 400, height: 400 };
  const boxSize = { width: 50, height: 50 };
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);
  const [currentWordIndex, setCurrentWordIndex] = useState(0);
  const [boxesClicked, setBoxesClicked] = useState(0);
  const totalBoxes = 3;

 const handleBoxClick = (event) => {
  if (!gameOver) {
    const box = event.target;
    const currentMeaning = words[currentWordIndex].currectBedeutungIndex;
    const clickedWord = box.getAttribute('data-word');
    if (box.style.display !== 'none') {
      if (clickedWord === currentMeaning) {
        box.style.display = 'none';
        setBoxesClicked((prevBoxesClicked) => prevBoxesClicked + 1);
        setCurrentWordIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
      } else {
        alert('Wrong word!');
      }
    }
    if (boxesClicked + 1 === totalBoxes) {
      setGameOver(true);
    }
  }
};



  const currentWord = words[currentWordIndex];  
  const currentMeaning = currentWord.bedeutung[0];

  return (
    <div className='part-four-container'>
      <div>
          <p className='bedeutung-container' key={0}>{currentMeaning}</p>
      </div>

      {!gameOver && (
        <div>
          <div
            className='hallo'
            data-word="hallo"
            style={{
              top: `${boxPosition.y}px`,
              left: `${boxPosition.x}px`,
            }}
            onClick={handleBoxClick}
            //onClick={(event) => handleBoxClick(event, 'hallo')}
           // onClick={(event) => handleBoxClick(event)}
            //onClick={hadleRightClick}
           //onClick={handleBoxClickAndRightClick}
          >
            hallo
          </div>

          <div
            className='danke'
            data-word="danke"
            style={{
              top: `${boxPosition.y * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)}px`,
              left: `${boxPosition.x * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)}px`,
            }}
            onClick={handleBoxClick}
           // onClick={(event) => handleBoxClick(event, 'danke')}
          // onClick={(event) => handleBoxClick(event)}
           //onClick={hadleRightClick}
          // onClick={handleBoxClickAndRightClick}
          >
            danke
          </div>

          <div
            className='gutenMorgen'
            data-word="gutenMorgen"
            style={{
              top: `${boxPosition.y * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)}px`,
              left: `${boxPosition.x * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)}px`,
            }}
            onClick={handleBoxClick}
          // onClick={(event) => handleBoxClick(event, 'gutenMorgen')}
       //   onClick={(event) => handleBoxClick(event)}
          //onClick={hadleRightClick}
         // onClick={handleBoxClickAndRightClick}
      > Guten Morgen</div>
      

</div>)}

        {gameOver && (
      <div >
        <p className='game-over'>Spiel ist aus</p>
      <button className='gam-over-button' onClick={handleRefreshClick}>nochmal abspielen</button>
       
      </div>
      )}

    </div>
  );
};

export default ParFour;
```

**my array**

```
const words = [
    {
        word: 'Hallo',
        bedeutung: ['مرحبا','اهلا'],
        currectBedeutungIndex: 0,
    },
    {
        word: 'Guten Morgen',
        bedeutung: ['صباح الخير','مرحبا'],
        currectBedeutungIndex: 0,
    },

]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`if (clickedWord === currentMeaning) {`

You are comparing the word that was inside the elements attribute with the index of the correct answer, which will always be false